# Retrive textcontent by matching start word and end word

Tags: java

I am getting text file with contents like below. I want to retrieve the data present between `start_word=Tax%` and `end_word="ErrorMessage"`.

```
ParsedText: 
Tax%    
63  2  .90  0.00  D INTENS  SH 80ML(48)     9.00%   9.00% 
23  34013090    0.0     DS PURE WHIT 1 COG (24)     9.00%   9.00%   
"ErrorMessage":"","ErrorDetails":""
```

After retreiving the output would be

```
63  2  .90  0.00  D INTENS  SH 80ML(48)     9.00%   9.00% 
23  34013090    0.0     DS PURE WHIT 1 COG (24)     9.00%   9.00%
```

Please help.

I am using camel to read the text then i want to retrive the data to process further as per my requiement.

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class DataExtractor implements Processor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String textContent=(String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
        System.out.println("TextContents >>>>>>"+textContent);

    }
```

}

In the text content I am getting the content that i have given above.I need help regarding retreiving the the data in java.

Comment: Now [edit] your question again and include the Java code that parses `textContent` as you require. Does it work?

Comment: Take a look at using [`indexOf`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-indexof/) in order to find the start and end indices based on the substrings (`Tax%` and `"Error Message"`), then grab the substring between those indices.

Comment: split your content on new line '\n' and then loop through array checking for start and end row. Maybe suggestion by @TheGamer007 is better, it depends what you plan to do with the rest of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code snippet to extract the desired output:

```
    String[] strArr = textContent.split("\\r?\\n");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean appendLines = false;
    for(String strLines : strArr) {
        if(strLines.contains("Tax%")) {
            appendLines = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(strLines.contains("\"ErrorMessage\"")) {
            break;
        }
        if(appendLines){
            stringBuilder.append(strLines);
            stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }

    textContent =  stringBuilder.toString();
```